# Unable to SSH into a docker container used for ssh tunneling - "load pubkey "/ssh_key/id_rsa.pem": invalid format"

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, lambda, ssh-tunnel

I'm having troubles setting up an ssh tunnel container to communicate with a postgres database while trying to run a lambda locally using docker. If that wasn't too confusing...

That local lambda pulls information from kinesis ( simulated in a python script) and the application then compares device data from kinesis container to the postgres container and then passes it along to redis (simulated in another container and proven connected).

Unfortunately, Postgres is using an ssh tunnel to connect to the dev database and I'm not sure there is another way.  The bastion that it's connected to is the id_rsa.pem file in the volume passed in the docker run command. I'm using those credentials and passed as `-i` in the ssh command but I'm getting `load pubkey "/ssh_key/id_rsa.pem": invalid format` however, when I check it, it appears valid:

```
~(SDO-44-python2.7)  openssl rsa -check -in ~/Dev/SDO-4/mar-atlas-readings-processor/tunnel/ssh_key/id_rsa.pem -noout
RSA key ok
```

Here is my tunnel project in a nut shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create network (--link is legacy and may not be supported later)
echo "Creating docker network named 'lambda_network'...";
docker network create lambda_network
echo "'lambda_network' is ready!";

# SSH tunnel
echo "Creating ssh tunnel for postgres...";
cd tunnel && \
docker build -t tunnel . && \
docker run -it --rm -p 3306:3306 \
    --network=lambda_network \
    --name=tunnel \
    -h lambda_container \
    -p 54320 \
    -e LOCAL_PORT=3306 \
    -e REMOTE_PORT=22\
    -e SSH_BASTION_HOST=XXXXXXXXX \
    -e REMOTE_SERVER_IP=XXXXXXXXX \
    -e SSH_USER=ec2-user \
     # the key I validated above is located in tunnel/ssh_key/id_rsa.pem
    -v ./ssh_key/:/ssh_key/:ro \ 
    tunnel;
cd .. && \
echo "Postgres is ready";

exit 0
```

Tunnel dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.12

RUN apk --no-cache add openssh-client
ADD run.sh /run.sh

# Security fix for CVE-2016-0777 and CVE-2016-0778
RUN echo -e 'Host *\nUseRoaming no' >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "/run.sh"]
```

Here is the run.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# create an ssh tunnel to a bastion host, then tunnel into db from there

chmod 400 /ssh_key/id_rsa

if [ -z ${REMOTE_SERVER_IP+x} ]; then
    REMOTE_SERVER_IP="127.0.0.1"
fi

if  [ -z ${SSH_PORT+x} ] ; then
    SSH_PORT="22"
fi

if [ -z ${LOCAL_PORT+x} ] || [ -z ${REMOTE_PORT+x} ] || [ -z ${SSH_BASTION_HOST+x} ] || [ -z ${SSH_USER+x} ] ; then 
    echo "some vars are not set"; 
    exit 1
fi

echo "starting SSH proxy $LOCAL_PORT:$REMOTE_SERVER_IP:$REMOTE_PORT on $SSH_USER@$SSH_BASTION_HOST:$SSH_PORT"

/usr/bin/ssh \
-NTC -o ServerAliveInterval=60 \
-o GatewayPorts=true \
-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
-L $LOCAL_PORT:$REMOTE_SERVER_IP:$REMOTE_PORT \
$SSH_USER@$SSH_BASTION_HOST \
-p $SSH_PORT \
-i /ssh_key/id_rsa.pem
```

I have also verified in another terminal that the ssh key file works as written.

**EDIT:** I was able to get it to work by using `EXPOSE 3306` in the tunnel dockerfile. It now is able to connect to the bastion manually from the terminal inside the docker tunnel container (not automatically with the run.sh file though). However, when I try to make the call from my other container through this tunnel, I get the following error:

```
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: wrong version number
```

Comment: is it the exrtension of `.pem`? I cannot change it to just `id_rsa` because docker treats it as a directory (unwanted obviously).

Comment: I tried .pub and no dice

Comment: Since `openssl rsa -check` doesn't work for public key for me,  you probably mix private and public key? There is `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` inside private.

Comment: It starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: next to your private, there should be public key generated - if I run `ls $HOME/.ssh/id*` I get `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` - private and public key. You can always generate new pair with `ssh-keygen`